# Why does an empty go program takes some time to finish?

Tags: macos, go

An empty Go program takes some time to finish (on Mac OS X). Why does it take so long?

```
$ go build -o main main.go
$ time ./main

real    0m0.725s
user    0m0.003s
sys 0m0.004s
$ cat main.go 
package main
func main() { }
$ ls -hgGl main
-rwxr-xr-x 1 1.2M 2021/02/22-21:04:47 main
$ go tool objdump main | wc -l
95974
$ file main
main: Mach-O 64-bit x86_64 executable
```

Comment: Can you check the Go version and how big is the generated binary? Also, check if the program is a static binary or linked to dynamic libraries?

Comment: How to check whether it is static of dynamic?

Comment: 'file main' should tell whether it is static or dynamic.

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: I think that 'file' reports that information on Linux, on Mac I can't really tell. You can also try 'ldd main'.

Comment: Does it take the same amount of time when you run it again (without compiling)?

Answer (score 1):

> Why does it take so long?

Because that's how long it takes to load execute and fininsh the program on your machine. 3ms is not much.

Answer (score 0):

An empty Go program is compiled to some machine instructions.

When you execute the program,  those instructions are actually loaded from storage to memory and executed.

You can take a peek at the assembly code of your compiled program:

go tool objdump binary_file

Comment: What am I supposed to see? The output of `go tool objdump main` is too long.

Comment: objdump should show the runtime code included to support the seemingly empty program, plus the code for func main itself.